# NullPointer Exception while xoring two byte arrays in android

Tags: android, cryptography

I have a question that, Iam xoring the first 2^21 bytes of a video file with an another byte array, but it gives a Null Pointer Exception while Xoring the bytes, I don't know why? Please suggest me the right answer of the same.

Thanks in advance.

**Error Stack:**

```
11-04 12:28:49.283: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(506): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-04 12:28:49.283: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(506): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example/com.example.TestCryptoActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-04 12:28:49.283: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(506):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
11-04 12:28:49.283: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(506):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
11-04 12:28:49.283: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(506):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
11-04 12:28:49.283: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(506):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
11-04 12:28:49.283: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(506):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-04 12:28:49.283: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(506):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-04 12:28:49.283: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(506):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-04 12:28:49.283: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(506):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-04 12:28:49.283: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(506):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-04 12:28:49.283: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(506):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
11-04 12:28:49.283: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(506):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
11-04 12:28:49.283: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(506):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-04 12:28:49.283: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(506): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-04 12:28:49.283: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(506):     at com.example.TestCryptoActivity.onCreate(TestCryptoActivity.java:132)
11-04 12:28:49.283: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(506):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-04 12:28:49.283: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(506):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
11-04 12:28:49.283: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(506):     ... 11 more
```

**Code:**

```
String str;
    StringBuffer strBuf = new StringBuffer();
    String episode="E0022505.mp4";
    int bytesRead;

    InputStream is;
    byte[] bytesafterXor;
    byte[] bytes;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        File file = new File("/sdcard/E0022505.mp4");
        try {
               is = new FileInputStream(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e2) {
               e2.printStackTrace();
        }
        byte[] fileData = new byte[2097152];
        int read = 0;
        while(read != fileData.length) {
           try {
            read += is.read(fileData, read, fileData.length - read);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bos.write(fileData,0,read);
        bytes = bos.toByteArray();
        try {
            String byteString = new String(bytes,"UTF-8");
            System.out.println("the bytes array of video:"+byteString);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        String data = "xyzzy734499639E0022505@a2+;%d3-";


        try {
            str = getHashCode(data);
            strBuf.append(str);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        for(int i=1;i<31;i++)
        {
            if(i<10)
            {
                str = String.valueOf(30)+String.valueOf(30+i)+str;
                try {
                    str = new String(getHashCode(str));
                } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }else
            {
                char[] num = String.valueOf(i).toCharArray();
                String firstIndex = String.valueOf(num[0]);
                String secondIndex = String.valueOf(num[1]);
                str = firstIndex + secondIndex+ str;
                try {
                    str = new String(getHashCode(str));
                } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            strBuf.append(str);
            System.out.println("The final string after hashing:"+strBuf.toString());
        }
        for(int j=0;j<bytes.length;j+=1024)
        {
            String str = strBuf.toString();
            byte[] newByte = str.getBytes();
            for(int k=0;k<str.getBytes().length;k++)
            {
                bytesafterXor[k] = (byte)((newByte[k]^bytes[k])& 0x000000ff);// this is the error position
                //System.out.println("The result after Xoring:"+bytesafterXor[k]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is no any 132 line number in my project, My total project length is 127, I don't know How it is showing line number 132

Comment: So TestCryptoActivity.java is only 127 lines long? That sounds very odd. What happens when you try to debug it?

Comment: I've edited my answer now I've spotted exactly where it happens to go wrong this time, but frankly it looks like you're trying to do something rather odd. I hope this is just a project for fun rather than anything serious - trying to invent your own crypto algorithm and implementation is almost *never* a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: Okay, I've just seen the comment saying "this is the error position" - it was mostly hidden, which made it harder to see.

The answer is simple - you've never allocated `bytesafterXor`. You need something like:

```
bytesafterXor = new byte[newByte.length];
```

just before the `k` loop.

However, you should *also* read the rest of this answer to correct other bad practices.

---

You've posted a lot of code without showing where the stack trace is pointing, but I suspect the problem could well be due to one of the several blocks you've got like this:

```
try {
       is = new FileInputStream(file);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e2) {
       e2.printStackTrace();
}
```

If the file isn't found, `is` is still going to be `null` afterwards... leading to a `NullPointerException` when you try to use it. Basically whenever you run into an exception, you're currently just trying to carry on regardless, with no attempt to take account of the fact that the previous operation has just failed.

I suggest you create a separate method which is declared to throw `IOException` (and anything else which might be thrown) and call *that* from your `onCreate` method. Then have just *one* catch block (in `onCreate`) so that if anything goes wrong in the "inner" method, you don't keep trying to carry on with it regardless.

Additionally:

- I see no reason for `is` (etc) to be instance variables rather than local variables
- You should close all your streams and any other unmanaged resources in `finally` blocks
- Your code would be considerably easier to understand and debug if you refactored it into small methods.
- I'm not an Android developer, but I doubt that doing all of this work in an `onCreate` method is good practice anyway - shouldn't you be doing this in a background thread?
- Using `String.getBytes()` without specifying an encoding is *generally* a bad idea, and this:

  ```
  for(int k=0;k<str.getBytes().length;k++)
  ```

  ... is going to create a new byte array on *every iteration*. You've created a byte array (`newByte`) - why aren't you using `newByte.length`?
- It's not clear what this loop is meant to achieve:

  ```
  for(int j=0;j<bytes.length;j+=1024)
  ```

  given that you're not using the value of `j` within the loop...

Comment: Jon I already pointed out the error position Please see the second last line comment

Comment: @SanatPandey: Please try to read your post as someone else might - that comment is almost *entirely* obscured. It's near the bottom of a very long piece of code, and you didn't bother to put it on a line on its own so it's only visible if you scroll horizontally. In future, please try to make life easier for those trying to help you. Read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: Nice answer. And yes you should definitely do all work that takes longer then some hundert millisces in a background thread.